# RabbitMQ channels idling issue | How to recover unacked AMQP messages | Javaclient consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

[image: Queue][image: Connections][image: Channel inside connection] I am a consumer for rabbitmq and using spring-amqp. Right now when i go into admin, all the connections are showing running but channels inside them are all idle (Prefetch:250, Unacked:250) .  Could you Please help? 
How to use this prefetch properly ? 
Do i need to close connections ? 
How can I increase channels per connection . Right now there is only one channel per connection. Following is the code configuration snippet. I am using out if the box spring amqp configuration for most of the things .Also I am using a custom rabbitmq message listener to ack or unack messages.

```
<!-- RabbitMQ configuration -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${rabbitmq.host}" port="${rabbitmq.port}" username="${rabbitmq.username}" password="${rabbitmq.password}" virtual-host="${rabbitmq.vhosts}" requested-heartbeat="${rabbitmq.requestedHeartBeat}"/>

    <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="rabbitJsonConverter"/>
    channel.Close
    <bean id="rabbitJsonConverter" class="rabbitmq.messages.converter.CustomJackson2JsonMessageConverter">
        <property name="classMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultClassMapper">
                <property name="defaultType" value="rabbitmq.messages.custom.dto.CustomRabbitMQMessage"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="manual" requeue-rejected="true">
        <rabbit:listener queue-names="${rabbitmq.queuename}" ref="customRabbitMQMessageListener" method="onMessage"/>
    </rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="customRabbitMQMessageListener" class="rabbitmq.messages.listener.CustomRabbitMQMessageListener" >
        <property name="customerAccountService" ref="customerAccountService" />
    </bean>
```

```
**Listener Code**
LOG.debug("***** LISTENING RABBITMQ MESSAGES START******");
        channel.basicRecover(true);
        try {
                boolean ack = performOperationsOnMessage(msg);
                if (ack) {
                    channel.basicAck(msg.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);
                } else
                    channel.basicNack(msg.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false, true);
                LOG.debug("***** LISTENING RABBITMQ MESSAGES FINISHED******");
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            LOG.error("Exception occured during perform Change operation, RabbitMQ message: " + exp.getMessage(), exp);
            channel.basicNack(msg.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false, true);
        }

private boolean performOperationsOnMessage(Message msg) {
        RabbitMQMessage message = null;
            try {
                message = (RabbitMQMessage) rabbitJsonConverter.fromMessage(msg);
            } catch (MessageConversionException exp) {
                LOG.warn("Exception occurred during the conversion or any other issue", exp);
                return true;
            }
        if (message == null || message.getOperation() == null || message.getResource() == null || message.getResource().getUuid() == null) {
            LOG.warn("Received an empty message  or emptry operation or empty resource or empty uuid from queue ");
            return true;
        }
        if (message.getOperation().equals(RabbitMQMessage.RossoOperation.remove.name())) {
            return performRemoveOperation(message);
        }
        if (message.getOperation().equals(RabbitMQMessage.RossoOperation.change.name())) {
            return performChangeOperation(message);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Show, please, a code of your `CustomRabbitMQMessageListener`. What does it do? Do you really call `channel.basicAck()` ?

Comment: You haven't described a problem - the numbers just mean there are 250 messages outstanding at each consumer. If you are not seeing progress, it means you have failed to ack or nack those messages. The broker will only allow prefetch unack'd messages. The word `idle` here doesn't mean anything - you'll have to ask the RabbitMQ engineers what it means (rabbitmq-users Google Group). It's not clear what you mean by "one channel per connection". As you can see, each consumer has its own channel.

Comment: @ArtemBilan : yes what I do is in the CustomRabbitMQMessageListener is that if I have performed the required action successfully on the message, then I do channel.basicAck() and in cases where I get internal exceptions or due to some constraints, I want to process that message later again, then i send channel.basicNack()

Comment: @GaryRussell - If I failed to acknowledge these messages and they have reached count where prefetch is equal to unacked messages, what should I do here to ack or nack these messages ? . Since rabbimq stops sending messages to channel once prefecth=unack. Also official rabbitmq messages say the following:

Comment: @GaryRussell - "This is done by setting a "prefetch count" value using the basic.qos method. The value defines the max number of unacknowledged deliveries that are permitted on a channel. Once the number reaches the configured count, RabbitMQ will stop delivering more messages on the channel unless at least one of the outstanding ones is acknowledged"

Comment: You say `>Also I am using a custom rabbitmq message listener to ack or unack messages.` but now I look at your container is configured with the default (AUTO), which means the container will automatically ack when the listener exits. So you must be doing something strange. You need to show your listener code so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: hello @GaryRussell, where did you see that container is configured with default auto ?  Could you also please let me know. As far as i understand, I have made acknowledge="manual" on the listener configuration. I am also adding listener code so that you can have a look. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - i have also added listener code. thanks.

Comment: Sorry; I missed that you have set manual acks. Your listener looks ok so the only other thing I can think of is the consumer thread is "stuck" in one of your downstream methods - `getUserForUID()`, `deleteCustomer()` etc. Take a thread dump to see what the listener container threads are doing. Also what version of spring-rabbit are you using?

Comment: And, please, be sure that you really can `channel.basicAck/basicNack` in all branches of your logic.

Comment: thanks  @GaryRussell / Artem. I have refractored complete code listener code as you would see above. Now there is no way message would remain unacknowledged. One question How will I recover unacknowledged messages. When you see listener code, I am using channel.basicRecover(true). I hope it works else do you know any alternate way. I saw on some forum they say to disconnect client/consumer and reconnect again to get unacked messages back, but do you have idea how to do that ? Since I have multiple nodes which are listening and a load balancer on top to consume which is never down-always online

Comment: Call `resetConnection()` on the `CachingConnectionFactory`.

Comment: @GaryRussell , Artem : By the way, fixing the listener worked. Now the queue is completely consumed and it is empty. I will update the answer. Kindly accept it. Thanks guys for your suggestions : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution for this problem was in the listener code that was configured for manual acknowledgement. There were some branches in the logic which were leaving the listener unable to acknowledge some messages and that's how unacked count on the channels reached prefetch (250) leaving RabbitMQ stopping sending messages to the channels.

Fix: As you would see the updated listener code in the question, it never leaves any message unacknowledged.
Also in the negative acknowledgement channel.basicNack(msg.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false, true), requeue (last variable in the signature) should be true so that messages can be requeued back to the same queue